# How can the return annotation of decorated method be reflected when decoration (which changes the return type) is done dynamically

Tags: python, python-typing

Using `ParamSpec` and generic types it is possible to create a decorator that preserves the annotations of the decorated method and optionally also change them. The works as expected when the method is directly decorated inline using the `@decorator` approach however, when the decorator is applied dynamically on a class method the change in return type is not reflected.

Using the following contrived example:

```py
import functools
import inspect
from typing import TYPE_CHECKING, Callable, List, ParamSpec, TypeVar

R = TypeVar("R")
P = ParamSpec("P")


def listifyresponse(func: Callable[P, R]) -> Callable[P, List[R]]:
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapped(*args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> List[R]:
        return [func(*args, **kwargs)]

    return wrapped


def listifyclassresponses(cls):
    for name, method in inspect.getmembers(cls):
        if inspect.isfunction(method):
            setattr(cls, name, listifyresponse(method))

    return cls


class Base:
    def check(self, v: str, w: str) -> bool:
        return v == w


class SubA(Base):
    pass


@listifyclassresponses
class SubB(Base):
    pass


class SubC(Base):
    @listifyresponse
    def check(self, v: str, w: str) -> bool:
        return super().check(v, w)


if TYPE_CHECKING:
    reveal_type(SubA().check("a", "b")) # False
    reveal_type(SubB().check("a", "b")) # [False]
    reveal_type(SubC().check("a", "b")) # [False]

print(SubA().check("a", "b")) # Revealed type is "builtins.bool"
print(SubB().check("a", "b")) # Revealed type is "builtins.bool"
print(SubC().check("a", "b")) # Revealed type is "builtins.list[builtins.bool*]"
```

I observed the same behavior when using a metaclass to update the methods instead of a class decorator.